# Recent posts script mess up blog posts

Tags: posts

I use this script to display recent posts:

```
<ul>
<?php query_posts('showposts=5'); ?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

<li><?php the_content_limit(250); ?></li>
<?php endwhile;?>
</ul>
```

I put this in the header.php. It does the job, but also all other posts and pages gets messed up. When I try to load any ordinary page (page.php) I get only content from two blog posts and similar problems. It is not the issue with the_content_limit. I also tried excerpt - and its the same.

Any ideas how to avoid the problem but still have recent posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this after your endwhile

```
 <?php wp_reset_query() ?>
```

Regards

Comment: you are welcome, as a little advise, is always a good practice to place a reset after your loop, so this way it won't crash is you are using anu other queries around like sidebars, footer, header among others, have fun :)